# How to integrated/combined/merged MovieLens and IMDb datasets?

Tags: dataset, imdb, recommendation-engine

Movie.csv of the MovieLens dataset contains only the MovieId, title, and genre features. But I'd like to add more features (and merge with movie.csv) like director and cast information. How can I do this? May I ask for suggestions to be informed about this subject?

Thank you..